# ManyToOne OnDelete set Null triggers foreign key constraint violation

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

The parent Entity assotiation field:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AnswersAspects::class, mappedBy="Users")
     */
    private $AnswersAspects;
```

And the child Entity assotiation field:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Users::class, inversedBy="AnswersAspects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $Users;
```

I have the onDelete="SET NULL" on the Child, but when I try to remove the parent, I get the FK violation error:
`An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('answers_notes', CONSTRAINT 'FK_71C7235F67B3B43D' FOREIGN KEY ('users_id') REFERENCES 'users' ('id'))`

Comment: Try `onDelete="CASCADE"` as per the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities)

Comment: Wouldn't it remove the child element? I need to remove the parent, but keep the child, that's why I am trying to set it to NULL